# How do I handle unexpected responses from the server with AngularJS asyncValidators?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm relatively new to AngularJS and started experimenting with the new asyncValidators provided in AngularJS 1.3 and really like what I see. I have a question, however, about how to handle non happy-path errors from the server.

When using asyncValidators, you return a promise, which makes sense. Assume we have a validator that asks the server if a productId is valid. A call is made to REST api and if the response comes back as 200, the productId is valid. If the response comes back as 404, the productId is invalid.

What is the best way to handle a response such as 500, or maybe a server timeout? If I return `promise.resolve`, then it tells the form that the productId is valid (which we don't know). If I return `promise.reject`, it tells the form that the productId is invalid (which we don't know). I thought I'd get cute and return an empty promise (`return $q.defer().promise;`) but that leaves the form as `$pending` waiting for a promise resolution that will never happen.

I've included a quick code sample below to demonstrate. If I am taking a completely backwards approach on this I am happy for any advice.

```js
app.directive('isValidProductId', ['$http', '$q', 'productService', function ($http, $q, productService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            ctrl.$asyncValidators.valid = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var result = productService.getProduct(value).then(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                },
                function (error) {
                    if (error.status == 404) {
                        // The productId is invalid
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    } else {
                        // *** What to do if the response is 500, for example?? ***
                    }
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a 500 error, then you could treat the response as valid in term of the current validation key, but set another validation key as invalid. So, keeping this answer quite generic by using $http, something along the lines of the following should work.

```
ngModelController.$asyncValidators.valid = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
  // Make sure to reset the error state from any previous error
  ngModelController.$setValidity('connectionError', true);

  return $http(...).catch(function(error) {
    if (error.status == 500) {
      ngModelController.$setValidity('connectionError', false);
    } else {
      return $q.reject();
    }
  });
});
```

You can then use the key `connectionError` in the template or controller, to show an appropriate message.

Comment: Thanks Michal - these seems like a reasonable pattern to follow.